# Why am I getting a 403 Error When accessing here.com?

Tags: authentication, authorization, here-api

We have an application that uses here.com apis.  The application had worked up until a month or so ago, but we are now getting a 403 error when trying to access it.  We have a freemium account and have not hit our max hits for the site.  What could be causing this?

Comment: May we know which API are you trying to access? The API URL or code snippet would help us check further.

Comment: Uxh6x1ltd76GuEa50BKr

Comment: The Account is deactivated . It's auto renewal is due since 25-03-2020. Hence you are getting this error and you can activate it.